# Why does I2C only run once in interrupt mode on STM32?

Tags: stm32, i2c

I've got a custom board with two stm32f4s (f411 and f446) that communicate via I2C. Now, I have two dummy programs, where f446 is configured as I2C slave and f411 is I2C master. If I just transmit from the master every 500ms or so with `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit()` and the slave is contantly polling in a while loop then I have success every time. However, when using `void HAL_I2C_MasterTxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)` to determine when the interrupt has been called if I then restart HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_IT() within that function, the interrupt never gets called again. Does anyone have any idea why this is the case? If i put a flag within the function and then poll that through an if statement in main then it works.

Example:

This only works once:

```
uint8_t hello = 100;
    int main(void)
    {
      HAL_Init();
      SystemClock_Config();
      MX_GPIO_Init();
      MX_USART2_UART_Init();
      MX_I2C1_Init();
      HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_IT(&hi2c1, 42, &hello, sizeof(hello));
      while (1)
      {
        //Do stuff
    }
    void HAL_I2C_MasterTxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
    {
      hello = hello + 1;
      HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_IT(&hi2c1, 42, &hello, sizeof(hello));
    }
```

This works every time:

```
uint8_t hello = 100;
uint8_t i2c_int_flag = 0;
    int main(void)
        {
          HAL_Init();
          SystemClock_Config();
          MX_GPIO_Init();
          MX_USART2_UART_Init();
          MX_I2C1_Init();
          HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_IT(&hi2c1, 42, &hello, sizeof(hello));
          while (1)
          {
             if(i2c_int_flag)
            {
              i2c_int_flag = 0;
              hello = hello + 1;
              HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_IT(&hi2c1, 42, &hello, sizeof(hello));
            }
            //Do stuff
        }
        void HAL_I2C_MasterTxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
        {
          i2c_int_flag = 1;
        }
```

Currently I am still just polling the slave using `HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive()`. I thought perhaps it was a timing issue and so added

```
 while (HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c3) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY)
 {
 }
```

into the callback but this didn't help the issue. Is there anything obvious with my code? Why can't I restart the interrupt within the callback? I have done this before in STM32 with other peripherals such as SPI so I can't see a reason here for I2C to be different.

Comment: These HAL functions come with no documentation at all, but they do come with source code.  You're going to need to read that source code, and get familiar with the chapter in the reference manual for your microcontroller family that describes the I2C peripheral.

Comment: Probably something along the lines of some interrupt-related variable getting reset when the interrupt returns

Comment: @Ben Voigt I am familiar. There's no obvious reason within the source code as to why the interrupt can't be re-enabled within the callback. I can see in the CR2 register that interrupt enable bit doesn't get set. If I then set it outside the callback it works - which doesn't make sense. Hence the confusion.

Comment: @ChrisD91: It doesn't *get* set when calling `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_IT`, or it doesn't *stay* set when the callback returns?  Do you know what line of code in `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_IT` is supposed to set that flag?  You may need to set a breakpoint and single-step through.

Comment: @BenVoigt Of course there is documentation, see this for example: https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1725-description-of-stm32f4-hal-and-lowlayer-drivers-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: @Noxet: That's nice.  Wonder why there is zero mention of it at https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF4/tree/master/Documentation

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, good question. They should really have an overview of all available documentation for all parts of the development.. Sometimes you just have to be lucky to find what you're looking for ^^

Comment: @Noxet, good discovery! I find that STMicros documentation is very difficult to find.